# How to play a normal video in Super Slow Motion Mode in iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, avplayer, slowmotion

I have created video player using [AVPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer). Video is playing very well. Now i am trying to play video in Super Slow Motion Mode. So i am changing **frameRate** value to 0.0001. But it seems AVPlayer unable to play in very slow mode. Kindly any expert suggest me or any other alternative.

This is play button clicked function.

```
- (void)playButtonPressed:(id)sender {
 [video1ControlView.player prepareToPlayVideo]; }


-(void)prepareToPlayVideo
{
if(self.outputFileInternal != nil)
{
    AVPlayer *currentPlayer  = [self player];
    currentPlayer.rate = self.frameRate; // here frameRate = 1 means, video play in normal play. if i will pass 0.25 then video will play slow mode but i want to play in **SUPER SLOW MOTION MODE**
    _playerStatus = PlayerStatusPlaying;
}
}
```

Comment: Please share the code that you have tried so far and any error messages that you are receiving

Comment: @AdamRichardson i have been updated with code.